# Why am I getting an outdated pub package dialogue?

Tags: dart, dart-editor, dart-eclipse-plugin

I am using the current version of Dart 1.7.0_dev. When I attempt to add a pub package I am getting the attached dialogue - an old version.

[image]

Even with a new install of Dart, I am getting it. I would like to use the new one that gave me a the previous dialogue that suggest the package while the name of the package is being entered.

It appears as if this is cached and I can' seem to get rid of it.

Comment: As far as I know from other questions you are using the Eclipse Dart plugin, don't you?

Comment: Same here with Dart Editor x64 on Linux.

Comment: No Gunter. I have just started testing the Eclipse Dart plugin less than a week. Before that I had the same issue using the standalone Dart editor that you get when you download from the Dart download site. All questions posted prior to my last two were all based on the standalone Dart editor, NOT the eclipse dart plugin. I posed this question because I thought something was wrong to have the same issue in both Eclipse dart plugin and the standalone dart editor.

Comment: I'm using the development version of the Dart Editor as well and also get this dialog for adding packages. I'm also puzzled as to why. I've accepted it so far, but I think it might be unintentional.

Comment: Any solution for this problem?

Comment: What makes you believe this is not the intended dialog? Given it's a desktop app, the dialog can't really be "cached"; are you sure this isn't what it's supposed to show?